# Can I use INSERT statement with select to make a condition?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

I want to create an insert but I want to check if the last insert of a table is null. When its null I dont want to insert it.

I have a table named users_ill.

```
id | user_id | health_at | created_at
```

Here is my insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO users_ill (user_id) VALUES ($1);', [user_id]);
```

But now I want to check also if the health_at is null or not. How can I check this with insert ?

I can also write another query but I think this would be not necessarry when its work with insert and select together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the most recent record would be the one with the greatest `created_at` value, you could use an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` as follows:

```sql
INSERT INTO users_ill (user_id)
SELECT $1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM (
        SELECT health_at
        FROM users_ill
        ORDER BY created_at DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) t
    WHERE health_at IS NULL
)
```

The inner `LIMIT` subquery finds the most recent record in the `users_ill` table.  The exists logic then asserts that the `health_at` value from that most recent record is *not* null.  The insert then would only proceed under the conditions you expect.